# Magento Coupon code doesnot work when From or To Date is specified

Tags: php, magento, coupon

I have a strange issue in my promotional rules.  When I select From Date or To Date or both when creating a shopping cart price rule in Magento, Magento says coupon is invalid.

As soon as, I removed those dates and apply the coupon, it works like a charm.

Is anyone facing the same kinda issue?
Awaiting the response.

- Version: CE 1.7.0.2
- Replaced the Checkout module of Magento core with the default one.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: are you facing this issue on local system or live server?

Comment: @techguy4web Live-  Its our remote testing server.

Comment: can you please let me know whats the date are you using in From & To date fields?

Comment: The date is within the range.  Basically this should work as I am Magento Developer myself but not able to trace the issue. :(